# Why does my BlueJ jar file load some images, but not others?

Tags: java, paintcomponent, jcomponent, javax

I used some of the information around this site to find out to use URLs to get images into a jar file; which I want to be able to be used alone. But when I make the jar file with BlueJ, only some images show up.

Its a blackjack game, and only the table canvas shows up, while no cards ever do. Here's the code:

THIS WORKS (the table):

```
public class TableComponent extends JLabel{

  BufferedImage table;


  public TableComponent(){
    URL finalTable = getClass().getResource("blackjackTableCanvas.jpg");
        try {
        table = ImageIO.read(finalTable);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  @Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g2);
    g2.drawImage(table, 0, 0, null);
}...}
```

but this does not (the cards):

```
public class CardRender2 extends JComponent{

  BufferedImage image;
  String val;
  String suit;
  String filename;

  public CardRender2(Card card) {
    this.val = card.value.face;
    this.suit = card.suit.toString();
    filename = this.fetchCardFileLabel();

    URL cardview = getClass().getResource("\\card deck\\" + filename + ".png");
    try {

      image = ImageIO.read(cardview);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
  public CardRender2(){
    this.val = null;
    this.suit = null;
    filename = "DEALER_FIRST_CARD";

    URL cardview = getClass().getResource("\\card deck\\DEALER_FIRST_CARD.png");
    try {

      image = ImageIO.read(cardview);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g2);
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

  }...}
```

my cards are in a folder in the directory I try to import into BlueJ, whereas the table is in the directory root. There are 53 cards in there (incl dealer hidden card) and I'd rather not put all of then in the root. I tried to implement them similarly. How can I do this?

Comment: So the image with the relative path shows up, but the ones with the absolute path don't ... isn't this already a pretty strong hint?

Comment: not for me. I've not been coding for long.

Comment: differing relative and absolute paths has not much to do with "coding".

Comment: are you saying that its impossible to do it the way I tried to do it, with the cards all in a folder?

Comment: Have you re-checked what relative and absolute paths are and have you tried using a relative path for your cards?

Comment: I see definitions, mainly related to things like web addresses, but I it's hard to make out what I need to do to my program.

Comment: Then this might be helpful: http://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/. Then you'll the difference in both file paths and can try to change them to see if that works.

Comment: I'm stumped; this is not linux and unix as your link says. I would very much appreciate a hand on this.

Comment: Android is based on Linux and the file paths are equal in their structure.

Comment: I've tried eliminating the slash in front of the folder in the card URL, that didn't work. I tried eliminating "card deck", no dice either.

Comment: When you're using relative paths, then you need to know "where" the current working directory is. Your first URL just includes the filename. Are the cards in same directory as that file? And if they are somewhere else, then you know the path related to that file from the first code, so you should be able to fix the relative path.

Comment: yes, the cards are inside a folder called "card deck", which is in the folder where the java files and the table picture are; the java files and picture are in a folder called blackjackProject, and folder "card deck" is in blackjackProject too.

Answer (score 0):

looks like changing from

```
URL cardview = getClass().getResource("\\card deck\\DEALER_FIRST_CARD.png");
```

to

```
 URL cardview = getClass().getResource("card deck/DEALER_FIRST_CARD.png");
```

did the trick.